# Конвертация переменной

Tags: c#

Вот скажите, я объявил переменную

```
int MyInt;
```

После чего хочу, чтобы консоль считала то, что я введу, и вот какой код я использую

```
MyInt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.RealLine());
```

Но вопрос **зачем конвертировать в int, то что и так было объявлено как int**?

Comment: нет, вы конвертируете в ``int`` то, что ввели в консоли ввиде строки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre) прав.

```
int MyInt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.RealLine());
```

1. Получили ввод `Console.RealLine()`
2. Преобразовали его в целое `Convert.ToInt32()`
3. Присвоили результат переменной `int MyInt = ...`

Конвертировать нужно, потому что стандартное преобразование String в Int не существует. Еще можно так

```
int MyInt = int.Parse(Console.RealLine());
```

Comment: А можно узнать тогда что такое Parse, где и как его применять?

Comment: Можно, и очень просто: [Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.int32.parse.aspx).

Comment: Ух ты... да тут походу по всему C# справка 0_о, спасибо за сайт, давно такое искал.

Comment: оказывается, человеку нужен был не Хэшкод, а MSDN=)

Answer (score 0):

Этот способ самый простой

`int MyInt;
MyInt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Правда учитывая что пользователь может ввести вместо цифр буквы. То лучше использовать такой способ

`int MyInt;
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out MyInt))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели {0}", MyInt);
}
else Console.WriteLine("Ошибка");`

Но если Вы уверенны в том что буквы не будут введены, то лучше не использовать этот способ, так как он не оптимизирован, в этом случае лучше тот что я показал выше.